# The meaning of "along with"

Tags: meaning, grammar

> Kensington Market was once an eastern European and Italian neighborhood, but the area changed ***along with*** its residents.

Would you please explain the word "along with" in this sentence?
Thanks

Comment: ***Along with sb/sth***:  - in addition to someone or something else:
*California, along with Florida and Hawaii, is among the most popular US tourist destinations.* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/along

Comment: This type of issue is easily found with a google search. Please show the research you performed or the question will be at risk of being closed.

Comment: It means “as the residents changed, so did the area.” They changed together, side-by-side as it were.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought it meant "the area changed by its residents" or "the new residents with their new traditions change the area's atmosphere".But according to your explanations the sentence means, "The area changed as like as the residents"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the exact meaning of the sentence is somewhat ambiguous.

As indicated in [the Merriam-Webster definition of *as well as*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20well%20as),

> :  and in addition :  and <brave as well as loyal>

the meaning can be as simple as *and,* and the example sentence might merely be saying that the area and its residents changed.

When two events are cause and effect, however, *as well as* also has the connotation of *because.* In that case, the effect is mentioned first,
then the cause. That is, the sentence might be intended to mean
that the residents changed, and therefore so did the area.

But there is yet another level of grammatical ambiguity.
The residents of an area can change by individually growing older, more sophisticated, richer, or poorer; or the residents can change because
the old residents move out and new residents move in.
Since the example states that the area was *once* an eastern European and Italian neighborhood,
we might infer that it is no longer, and that the change in the residents was the replacement of old residents by new ones.
Yet the area did not get moved away and replaced by a new area;
instead, it remained in place and merely acquired more of some characteristics and less of others.

So when the example sentence says "the area *changed* along with its residents" [emphasis added], it seems likely that it was intended to say that
the area was *modified* because its residents were *replaced.*
That is, the word change is used syntactically as a single verb,
but it is used in two different senses.
This is an example of a [zeugma](https://literarydevices.net/zeugma/).
The phrase *as well as* participates in this zeugma by syntactically linking the two objects that invoke the two conflicting meanings of *change.*